# Which type of aircraft carrier is more cost-effective and more reliable in the long run?

Tags: ships, naval-engineering

All of the >100,000 tonnes US aircraft carriers are nuclear-powered.

On the other hand, all Chinese and British aircraft carriers are conventional powered.

Which type of aircraft carrier is more cost-effective and reliable in the long run? And, why?

Comment: How about "which power supply failure is cheaper to contain"? A nuclear explosion or an oil-based fuel leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It is just a choice.

Reliability is not at issue here.  Both power plants can be built to run whn they need to.

The cost of a nuclear powered ship far outweighs the conventional one.  Both building and maintaining the nuclear ship will cost likely twice what the conventional one does.  In addition, you have massive training costs for the nuclear sailors and officers, and you need more of them to run a nuclear ship.  The training is widely acknowledged as the most difficult academic courses in the US military.

Cost effective is something else. The US wants nuclear carriers because replenishing fuel oil takes away from aircraft launch & retrieval operations.  Carriers still need to replenish jet fuel and stores, but avoiding the time to bring aboard ship's propulsion fuel leaves more time for aircraft operations. Current carriers are also very fast, but this is more a design decision than an advantage of nuclear.

The US can afford to deploy these expensive assets, so it does.  It can also afford to have enough of these ships to account for the 4+ year refueling times for the ships.  We probably shouldn't discount the prestige aspect and the power of the internal nuclear power community, but nuclear ships do what the US Navy wants them to.